# merge pandas dataframes with objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge 3 pandas dataframes on the key 'id', but somehow cannot get to the right result.

In the end I want a dataframe with 2 rows, one with id 'abc' and objects (something, 1), (something1,1) and a row with id 'def' with object2 (something,1) and objects (something,1).
Is there any way to achieve this with pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[]])
df1['id'] ='abc'
df1['object'] = -1
df1['object'] = df1['object'].astype('object')
df1.at[0,'object'] = ('something', 1)
df1['object3'] = -1
df1['object3'] = df1['object3'].astype('object')
df1.at[0,'object3'] = ('something1', 1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[]])
df2['id'] ='def'
df2['object2'] = -1
df2['object2'] = df2['object2'].astype('object')
df2.at[0,'object2'] = ('something2', 1)


df3 = pd.DataFrame([[]])
df3['id'] ='def'
df3['object3'] = -1
df3['object3'] = df3['object3'].astype('object')
df3.at[0,'object3'] = ('something3', 1)
```

edit:

Sorry my original question was not clear: I would like the dataframe to look like following in the end:

```
| id  | object          | object2          | object3          |
|-----|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
| abc | ('something',1) | None             | ('something1',1) |
| def | None            | ('something2',1) | ('something3',1) |
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want the final result to look like.

Comment: Could you please explain your output a little more, or show how it should like ?

Comment: yes, absolutely. Sorry for that @piRSquared! I put an example of how I want my dataframe to look like as an edit to the post

Comment: I don't understand why id `'abc'` has a `('something1', 1)` in the `'object3'` column.  Oh wait, you updated the initial data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `concat` and `groupby`

Use `first` to resolve potential non-uniqueness.  This is fairly robust.

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).groupby('id', as_index=False).first()

    id          object          object3          object2
0  abc  (something, 1)  (something1, 1)              NaN
1  def             NaN  (something3, 1)  (something2, 1)
```